# Homogeneous equation with constant coefficient, help with problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

the answer I got for solving this problem is different than the answer in the book. Are they by any chance equivalent, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEP5H.jpg
image too big for this website, sorry!

Thank you!

Comment: you didnt write the vectors in the final answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$x' = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 \end{pmatrix} x ,~~~~~ x(0) = \begin{pmatrix} 3 \\  1 \end{pmatrix}$$

You found the correct eigenvalues

$$\lambda_1 = 4, \lambda_2 = 1$$

For $\lambda_1 = 4$, we have the RREF of $[ A -\lambda_1 I]v_1 = 0$ as

$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}v_1 = 0$$

This leads to an eigenvector of

$$v_1 = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

You have the same sign issue in your second eigenvector calculation and these are causing your issues.

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!!!